# What is the equivalent of express' res.sendStatus(200) on Next.js api serverless functions?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I was used to do the following in some of my `express` routes.

```
return res.sendStatus(200);
```

But the `res` object from `NextApiHandlerType` does not allow that method.

What would be the equivalent, in this case?

```
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";

const handler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
  // DO STUFF
  return res.???   // WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO RETURN THE status CODE WITH THE STANDARD CODE MSG ?
};
```

I'm currently doing this, but it seems redundant.

```
return res.status(200).send("Ok");
```

From: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `end`, e.g, `res.status(200).end()`?

Comment: @juliomalves not yet. will try that!

Comment: @juliomalves It works, but it's not exactly the same and `senStatus(200)`. Just tried `res.status(200).end()` and it comes with the correct status code but with an empty response body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this is currently **not possible** inside a Next.js serverless function. I'm using  `"next": "10.1.3"`.

The closest alternative is, indeed:

```
return res.status(200).send("Ok");
```

Answer (score 7):

To anyone seeing this now, I was wondering the same thing.  The docs aren't 100% clear IMO.  This sends a status code and closes out the request.

```
res.status(200).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can find in the documentation :

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers

> The response (res) includes a set of Express.js-like methods to improve the developer experience and increase the speed of creating new API endpoints, take a look at the following example:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'Next.js' })
}
```

Comment: I don't want to send anything. I just need to send a status + standard msg. It seems that I need to send something anyway. Because doing this `res.status(200).send()` won't work. The `send` method needs a parameter. So what I want is not possible?